# Ubuntu 14.04 automatic login doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, unity, login, lightdm

In system settings I have turned on automatic login and `/etc/lightdm/*` files seems good, but after boot I get to Ubuntu desktop for a moment (about 1 second) and then it logged me off and I then must type password to login.

I am using ubuntu-desktop and unity-greeter and here is content of **lightdm.log**:

```
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.10.6, UID=0 PID=1520
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/90-nvidia.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xlocal
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module unity
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module surfaceflinger
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Adding default seat
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat: Starting
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat: Creating user session
[+0.15s] DEBUG: Loading users from org.freedesktop.Accounts
[+0.15s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 added
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Seat: Creating display server of type x
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Deactivating Plymouth
[+0.28s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.28s] DEBUG: Seat: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+0.28s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.28s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.28s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Launching X Server
[+0.28s] DEBUG: Launching process 1542: /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+0.28s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+0.28s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.28s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+0.84s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 1542
[+0.84s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Got signal from X server :0
[+0.84s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Connecting to XServer :0
[+0.84s] DEBUG: Quitting Plymouth; retaining splash
[+0.86s] DEBUG: Launching process 1550: /sbin/prime-offload
[+0.87s] DEBUG: Process 1550 exited with return value 0
[+0.87s] DEBUG: Seat: Exit status of /sbin/prime-offload: 0
[+0.87s] DEBUG: Seat: Display server ready, starting session authentication
[+0.87s] DEBUG: Session pid=1561: Started with service 'lightdm-autologin', username '<MyUserName>'
[+0.92s] DEBUG: Session pid=1561: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+0.92s] DEBUG: Seat: Session authenticated, running command
[+0.92s] DEBUG: Registering session with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
[+0.92s] DEBUG: Session pid=1561: Running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
[+0.92s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/<MyUserName>
[+0.92s] DEBUG: Session pid=1561: Logging to .xsession-errors
[+0.93s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+0.93s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c1
[+1.60s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 changed
[+14.70s] DEBUG: Session pid=1561: Exited with return value 0
[+14.70s] DEBUG: Seat: Session stopped
[+14.70s] DEBUG: Seat: Stopping display server, no sessions require it
[+14.70s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 1542
[+14.80s] DEBUG: Process 1542 exited with return value 0
[+14.80s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: X server stopped
[+14.80s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+14.80s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+14.80s] DEBUG: Seat: Display server stopped
[+14.80s] DEBUG: Launching process 2219: /sbin/prime-switch
[+14.85s] DEBUG: Process 2219 exited with return value 0
[+14.85s] DEBUG: Seat: Exit status of /sbin/prime-switch: 0
[+14.85s] DEBUG: Seat: Active display server stopped, starting greeter
[+14.85s] DEBUG: Seat: Creating greeter session
[+14.85s] DEBUG: Seat: Creating display server of type x
[+14.85s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+14.85s] DEBUG: Seat: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+14.85s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+14.85s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+14.85s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Launching X Server
[+14.85s] DEBUG: Launching process 2250: /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+14.85s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+14.93s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 2250
[+14.93s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Got signal from X server :0
[+14.93s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Connecting to XServer :0
[+14.93s] DEBUG: Launching process 2253: /sbin/prime-offload
[+14.94s] DEBUG: Process 2253 exited with return value 0
[+14.94s] DEBUG: Seat: Exit status of /sbin/prime-offload: 0
[+14.94s] DEBUG: Seat: Display server ready, starting session authentication
[+14.94s] DEBUG: Session pid=2261: Started with service 'lightdm-greeter', username 'lightdm'
[+14.94s] DEBUG: Session pid=2261: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+14.94s] DEBUG: Seat: Session authenticated, running command
[+14.94s] DEBUG: Session pid=2261: Running command /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/sbin/unity-greeter
[+14.94s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/lightdm
[+14.94s] DEBUG: Session pid=2261: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log
[+14.95s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+14.95s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c2
[+15.04s] DEBUG: Session pid=2261: Greeter connected version=1.10.6
[+15.17s] DEBUG: Session pid=2261: Greeter start authentication for <MyUserName>
[+15.17s] DEBUG: Session pid=2311: Started with service 'lightdm', username '<MyUserName>'
[+15.18s] DEBUG: Session pid=2311: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+15.18s] DEBUG: Session pid=2261: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+15.71s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 changed
[+24.01s] DEBUG: Session pid=2261: Continue authentication
[+24.02s] DEBUG: Session pid=2311: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+24.02s] DEBUG: Session pid=2261: Authenticate result for user <MyUserName>: Success
[+24.02s] DEBUG: Session pid=2261: User <MyUserName> authorized
[+24.02s] DEBUG: Session pid=2261: Greeter requests session ubuntu
[+24.02s] DEBUG: Seat: Stopping greeter; display server will be re-used for user session
[+24.02s] DEBUG: Session pid=2261: Sending SIGTERM
[+24.02s] DEBUG: Session pid=2261: Exited with return value 0
[+24.02s] DEBUG: Seat: Session stopped
[+24.02s] DEBUG: Seat: Greeter stopped, running session
[+24.02s] DEBUG: Registering session with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session1
[+24.02s] DEBUG: Session pid=2311: Running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
[+24.02s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/<MyUserName>
[+24.02s] DEBUG: Session pid=2311: Logging to .xsession-errors
[+24.04s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+24.04s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c3
[+25.53s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 changed
[+625.89s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 changed
[+2064.46s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 changed
[+2136.03s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 changed
```

`<MyUserName>` stands for my real username.

PS: I have uninstalled seahorse (Passwords and Keys), could this cause my problem?

Comment: Is there anything helpful in your `~/.xsession-errors` file?

Comment: @steeldriver Sorry, but I already solved it by reinstalling Ubuntu ... I will not remove this question because of others that suffer by this issue. Thank you.